# div content over div fixed on scroll?

Tags: css

I have a div fixed on the top and a div content below it.

When I scroll the page I want div `content` to be over the div `top`, I put z-index in div content but nothing happens...

```
#top{
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:black;
}

#content{
  background:red;
  margin-top:120px;
  height:5000px;
  z-index:300000;
}
```

html

```
<div id=top></div>
<div id=content></div>
```

I need div top to be fixed and content relative.

what is wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/y97o6kaL/

Comment: Check my answer. But i didn't understood if you do not want to show header/top then why you want to set it fixed?

Comment: @ketan thank you! it is just to do an effect when you scroll the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `z-index: -1;` to `#top` will work for you.

```
#top{
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y97o6kaL/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would add `position: relative;` to the `#content` div.

This would remove the need for any `z-index` styles.

```css
#top{
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:black;
}

#content{
  background:red;
  margin-top:120px;
  height:5000px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id=top></div>

<div id=content></div>
```

Comment: oh, it works! I thought I don't need to add `position: relative` in my divs because it is the default position... Am I wrong?

Comment: By default `divs` are `position:static;`